# Retrieve and compare time from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, phpmyadmin

Hello I wasn't able to retrieve time data from database and display it on my site.
I think that my problem is in while loop or comparing time in if statement.
I'm positive that sql query is correct because I checked it.
Below is my code. Thantks for helping me.

```
$timeSql = "SELECT `Godzina_od`, `Godzina_do` FROM `godziny_przyjec` WHERE Id_dnia_przyjec = '$idDniaRow[Id_dnia]' and Id_uzytkownika = '$idLekarza'";
$timeResult = $connection->query($timeSql);
$timeRow = $timeResult->fetch_assoc();

$tStart = strtotime($timeRow['Godzina_od']);
$tEnd = strtotime($timeRow['Godzina_do']);

$getTimeResult = $connection->query("SELECT `Godzina` FROM `wizyty_lekarskie` WHERE Id_dnia ='$idDniaRow[Id_dnia]'  and Id_lekarza_prowadzacego = '$idLekarza'");

while($tStart < $tEnd)
{
    while($getTimeRow = $getTimeResult->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if(strtotime($getTimeRow['Godzina']) != $tStart)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.date("H:i", $tStart).'">'.date("H:i", $tStart).'</option>';
            $tStart = strtotime('+20 minutes', $tStart);
        }
        else
        {
            $tStart = strtotime('+20 minutes', $tStart);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `$idDniaRow[Id_dnia]` to `{$idDniaRow['Id_dnia']}`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using only one while loop remove the second while loop, and retrieve

```
    $tStart = strtotime($timeRow['Godzina_od']);
$tEnd = strtotime($timeRow['Godzina_do']);                 as                               

    $tStart = $timeRow['Godzina_od'];
$tEnd = $timeRow['Godzina_do'];        then do you strotime outside                               that would work if you do this two things else contact me
```